# Is there a laptop where you can turn off the backlight of the screen completely?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, backlight

Is there a laptop where you can turn off the backlight of the screen completely?

I have a Pixel Qi tablet where you can turn off the backlight and I use that function all the time. Really saves the eyes if you read or write a lot.

Now, I would like to have that functionality in a laptop too, preferably with a 13.3 inch laptop screen or so.

I don't know how well the Pixel Qi company is doing, haven't seen a lot of updates from they're lately. Maybe there's another company which manufactures a similar screen that you can tip me about?

Again, I'm looking for a laptop where you can turn off the backlight of the screen entirely. Perhaps a Mirasol screen, or did that product turn into vaporware too?

The technology behind is somewhat irrelevant - what's important is that I want to be able to turn off the backlight.

Any tips?

Comment: http://blog.matchgenius.com/debian-turn-off-lcd-backlight/

Answer (score 2):

Although shopping requests/recommendations are off-topic for SU, and I think finding a notebook with this specific functionality would be impossible (never seen or heard of one personally), here's a generic hack that could work with many notebooks:

- Open your notebook's LCD shell.
- Find the two power lines that run to the LCD backlight's power inverter (assuming not LED backlit).
- Put a small toggle switch inline with one of the wires.
- Mount the toggle switch through the chassis/shell someplace.
- Profit. :)

[image: Inverter]

[image: small toggle]

Comment: Is it really that easy? Are you saying that Pixel Qi technology does not add anything but a switch to screens? Are you certain that a normal screen would really display anything at all if the backlight were completely turned off.

Comment: I'm unfamilliar with Pixel Qi's products.  My general experience is, if you turn off the backlight, you aren't reading anything (without being on a certain angle so room light reflects off it). :)

Comment: That's how I use the tablet right now, I can work on it using reflected light only. The question is whether your technique would produce a similar result to using a Pixel Qi screen or if it would differ somewhat : )